# Swing GUI too big for screen

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm developing a `Swing` `GUI` which is rather sizeable due to many components being displayed:

```
setSize(1200, 740); // width, height
```

I'm setting the absolute sizes like this because `pack()` cuts off the `GUI` on the right even though there are components. I cannot make it smaller because all the elements should be visible and this is the smallest it gets before cutting something off.

The problem is that some users/screen resolutions are so small that the whole `GUI` does not fit on the screen.

What can be done to resolve this problem? Can the `GUI` be sized according to the PC screen resolution without ever cutting off components on it? I'm using [`IntelliJ IDEA's form designer`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/designing-gui-major-steps.html) to build the `GUI` because it is fairly convenient.

Comment: *"I'm setting the absolute sizes like this because pack() cuts off the GUI on the right even though there are components"* - Then there is something wrong with the way you are laying out your components. *"I'm using IntelliJ IDEA's form designer to build the GUI because it is fairly convenient."* - Convenience in this case is costing you flexibility. Yes, Swing is more the capable of doing what you want, but you are doing something the is disabling that functionality, using a `null` layout or overriding the preferred/minimum/maximum sizes in some way

Comment: @MadProgrammer:
I'm using the IntelliJ GridLayoutManager: https://www.formdev.com/jformdesigner/doc/layouts/intellijgridlayout/.

It's still a layout manager after all, the window can be resized just fine and I'm not setting component sizes specifically.

Comment: Without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it's simply guess work - the fact is, it works fine for me, has done for the past 18 years, so I can only assume that  you've done something in your code which is causing your issues

Comment: If the problem isn't the layout, then the problem is your form. You are trying to fit too much data on one form. So you need to either 1) redesign the form and maybe use popup windows for additional information. 2) make the entire content pane scrollable so the user can reach all the components.